# Insert array values to sqlite database in C# application

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a C# application which retrieves the required information and stores it in a array, I am using Finisar sqlite to create my database entry.

Can anybody guide me as to how I can write retrieved array values to the sqlite database. Any help will be extremely thankful.

Comment: Would be better if we see your work and where you stuck.

Comment: Thanks 4 replying Soner and I was able to figure out the solution to my problem, problem that I faced was that I was having an **string array** with all the retrieved value from a LOG file which I wanted to feed to my _Sqlite Db_, but I was having trouble as to how can I INSERT the array indexed value into created TABLES. Doing some trials I was able to INSERT to table VALUES in either ways: firstly, `INSERT INTO tablename(Id, X, Y.....) VALUES ('" + array[index] + "', '" + array[index] + "'.....)` and,

Comment: secondly, storing sql query as string as `INSERT INTO tablename(Id, X, Y...) VALUES (@v1, @v2..)` and since I was using sqlite I initialized new SQLiteCommand passing query string and sqlite_connection as parameter as `sql_cmd=new SQLiteCommand(query, sql_con)` using the sql_cmd I was able to add parameter to the command as `sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@v1", array[index])` and after adding all the parameter executed the query as `sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. In my case, I had a global array and inserted it into sqlite db.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(/*Your Connection String*/);

string AddFormationTop = "INSERT INTO Formation (WellID, Param1, Param2, Param3) 
VALUES ((SELECT WellID FROM Wells WHERE WellName = @WellName), @Param1, @Param2, @Param3)";

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(AddFormationTop, con);

string pParam1;
double pParam2;
double pParam3;

con.Open();
// of course, your "for" case might be different.  
for (int i = 1; i < GlobalVar.Formation.Length - 1; i++)
{
     pParam1 = GlobalVar.Param1[i];
     pParam2 = Convert.ToDouble(GlobalVar.Param2[i]);
     pParam3 = Convert.ToDouble(GlobalVar.Param3[i]);

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WellName", Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveWell);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", pParam1);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", pParam2);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", pParam3);

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}

con.Close();
```